# ruby on rails use openid auth Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

I use ruby-openid to allow auth with openid

when i use ruby 1.8 with rails as below:

```
ii  rails                                                  2.3.5-1.2+squeeze1           MVC ruby based framework geared for web application development
ii  rails-ruby1.8                                          2.3.5-1.2+squeeze1           MVC ruby based framework geared for web application development
ii  rake                                                   0.8.7-2                      a ruby build program
ii  ruby                                                   4.5                          An interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby
ii  ruby1.8                                                1.8.7.302-2squeeze1          Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby 1.8
ii  ruby1.8-dev                                            1.8.7.302-2squeeze1          Header files for compiling extension modules for the Ruby 1.8
ii  rubygems                                               1.3.7-3                      package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
ii  rubygems1.8                                            1.3.7-3                      package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
```

everything work fine.

but when i update to:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 3.2.2
1.8.11
```

after auth succ from the the OpenID Provider and return to my page, exception raised:

Verification failed: Unexpected parameter (not on return_to): 'controller'=nil)

i try to read idres.rb and found:

```
 @message.get_args(BARE_NS).each_pair do |bare_key, bare_val|
     rt_val = return_to_parsed_query[bare_key]
     if not return_to_parsed_query.has_key? bare_key
         # This may be caused by your web framework throwing extra
         # entries in to your parameters hash that were not GET or
         # POST parameters.  For example, Rails has been known to
         # add "controller" and "action" keys; another server adds
         # at least a "format" key.
         raise ProtocolError, ("Unexpected parameter (not on return_to): "\
             "'#{bare_key}'=#{rt_val.inspect})")
      end 
      if rt_val != bare_val
          raise ProtocolError, ("Parameter '#{bare_key}' value "\
              "#{bare_val.inspect} does not match "\
              "return_to's value #{rt_val.inspect}")
```

i am a newbie to ruby. how to solve this ? thanks very much

log below:

```
Started GET "/consumer/start" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:26 +0800 Processing by ConsumerController#start as HTML Redirected to http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server?openid.assoc_handle=e25c42b0-6774-11e1-9fdb-8f540be9bc3e&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fstutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com%2F&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fstutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com%2F&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2F114.113.197.25%3A3000%2Fconsumer&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2F114.113.197.25%3A3000%2Fconsumer%2Fcomplete%3Fdid_sreg%3Dy&openid.sreg.required=email%2Cnickname%2Cfullname Completed 302 Found in 4914ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/consumer/complete?did_sreg=y&openid.sreg.fullname=tiredboy&openid.assoc_handle=e25c42b0-6774-11e1-9fdb-8f540be9bc3e&openid.response_nonce=2012-03-06T10%3A12%3A32ZzI16RQ%3D%3D&openid.sreg.email=stumyreg%40gmail.com&openid.sreg.nickname=tiredboy&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fpip.verisignlabs.com%2Fserver&openid.pape.auth_policies=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.openid.net%2Fpape%2Fpolicies%2F2007%2F06%2Fnone&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fstutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com%2F&openid.sig=yNsdpak%2FyNi%2BcFp0oxmjtL3DmoY%3D&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fstutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com%2F&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.auth_time=2012-03-06T07%3A16%3A09Z&openid.signed=assoc_handle%2Cidentity%2Cresponse_nonce%2Creturn_to%2Cclaimed_id%2Cop_endpoint%2Cns.sreg%2Csreg.nickname%2Csreg.email%2Csreg.fullname%2Cns.pape%2Cpape.auth_policies%2Cpape.auth_time&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2F114.113.197.25%3A3000%2Fconsumer%2Fcomplete%3Fdid_sreg%3Dy" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Processing by ConsumerController#complete as HTML  Parameters: {"did_sreg"=>"y", "openid.sreg.fullname"=>"tiredboy", "openid.assoc_handle"=>"e25c42b0-6774-11e1-9fdb-8f540be9bc3e", "openid.response_nonce"=>"2012-03-06T10:12:32ZzI16RQ==", "openid.sreg.email"=>"stumyreg@gmail.com", "openid.sreg.nickname"=>"tiredboy", "openid.ns"=>"http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0", "openid.mode"=>"id_res", "openid.op_endpoint"=>"http://pip.verisignlabs.com/server", "openid.pape.auth_policies"=>"http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/none", "openid.claimed_id"=>"http://stutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com/", "openid.sig"=>"yNsdpak/yNi+cFp0oxmjtL3DmoY=", "openid.identity"=>"http://stutiredboy.pip.verisignlabs.com/", "openid.ns.pape"=>"http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0", "openid.pape.auth_time"=>"2012-03-06T07:16:09Z", "openid.signed"=>"assoc_handle,identity,response_nonce,return_to,claimed_id,op_endpoint,ns.sreg,sreg.nickname,sreg.email,sreg.fullname,ns.pape,pape.auth_policies,pape.auth_time", "openid.ns.sreg"=>"http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1", "openid.return_to"=>"http://114.113.197.25:3000/consumer/complete?did_sreg=y"} Redirected to http://114.113.197.25:3000/consumer Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/consumer" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Processing by ConsumerController#index as HTML  Rendered consumer/index.html within layouts/application (0.3ms) Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms) [2012-03-06 18:12:32] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms) [2012-03-06 18:12:32] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms) [2012-03-06 18:12:32] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 218.107.55.254 at 2012-03-06 18:12:32 +0800 Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms) [2012-03-06 18:12:32] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: Can you paste the complete backtrace please ?

Comment: please do it yourself. it's not hard :(

Comment: There are no backtrace on you add :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*** /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/idres.rb 2012-03-06 15:13:54.000000000 +0800
--- /home/tiredboy/login/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ruby-openid-2.1.8/lib/openid/consumer/idres.rb 2012-03-07 13:25:58.000000000 +0800
***************
*** 170,175 ****
--- 170,178 ----
          end
          @message.get_args(BARE_NS).each_pair do |bare_key, bare_val|
            rt_val = return_to_parsed_query[bare_key]
+           if bare_key == "controller" or bare_key == "action"
+             next
+           end
            if not return_to_parsed_query.has_key? bare_key
              # This may be caused by your web framework throwing extra
              # entries in to your parameters hash that were not GET or
```

i ignore controller and action as temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

It's problem created by Rails, it sometimes adds some parameters like "controller" and "action" in the url.

Instead of modifying the source of idres.rb, you can modify your Rails controller in which you manage the return call in this way:

```
parameters = params.reject{|k,v|request.path_parameters[k]}.reject{|k,v| k == 'action' || k == 'controller'}
```

like I found in an [issue](https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/issues/31) on the ruby-openid gem on GitHub

This solved the problem for me.